# 3 Regular Graph. Planar?

Tags: graph-theory

If a graph is 3 colourable and is 3 regular, non hamiltonian, can I be assured that it is non-planar? i.e can I be assured that $K_{33}$ is a subgraph.

Comment: By the way, I think you mean $K_{3,3}$, not $K_{33}$, which is a different graph. The comma is important.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can not be assured that such a graph is non-planar.

The standard counter-example is the **Tutte graph**:
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_graph

Comment: Is there an algorithm to check if $K_{33}$ is a subgraph?

Comment: Yes, there is a polynomial time algorithm for checking whether a given graph contains $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph. This follows from the graph minor theory of Robertson and Seymour.